# How can I see errors in nodejs stdout?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I modified some ts code in node and now the pages look empty, i would like to see some errors at specific lines in code, but terminal where node is launched is empty - should it write console.warn on stdout?

```
 // @ts-ignore
    process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
      console.warn('Unhandled Rejection at:', promise, 'reason:', reason);
    });
    // @ts-ignore
    process.on('uncaughtExceptionMonitor', (err, origin) => {
      console.warn('Unhandled Rejection at:');
    });
    // @ts-ignore
    process.on('uncaughtException', (err, origin) => {
      console.warn('Unhandled Rejection at:');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[console.warn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/warn) prints only warning messages.

You can refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console) and use the corresponding function which suits your requirement.